# Dart - type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to parse a local JSON file in dart and to display its values.

user.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Greg",
        "imageUrl": "assets/images/greg.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "James",
        "imageUrl": "assets/images/james.jpg"
    }
]
```

Here is my chats.json

```
[
    {
        "sender": "james",
        "time": "5:30 PM",
        "text": "Hey, how's it going? What did you do today?",
        "isLiked": false,
        "unread": true
    },
    {
        "sender": "olivia",
        "time": "4:30 PM",
        "text": "Hey, how's it going? What did you do today?",
        "isLiked": true,
        "unread": false
    }
]
```

Here is my Message class

```
class Message {
  final User sender;
  final String time;
  final String text;
  final bool isLiked;
  final bool unread;

  Message({
    this.sender,
    this.time,
    this.text,
    this.isLiked,
    this.unread,
  });

  factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return Message(
      sender: User.fromJson(parsedJson['sender']),
      time : parsedJson['time'],
      text : parsedJson ['text'],
      isLiked : parsedJson['isLiked'],
      unread : parsedJson ['unread'],      
    );
  }

  static List<User> parseUsers(usersJson) {
    List<User> usersList = new List<User>.from(usersJson);
    return usersList;
  }
}
```

Here is my user class

```
class User {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String imageUrl;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.imageUrl,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return User(
      id: parsedJson['id'],
      name : parsedJson['name'],
      imageUrl : parsedJson ['imageUrl']
    );
  }

}
```

Here is my latest_chat.dart (it's StatefulWidget)

```
List<Message> _messages = List<Message>();

  Future<String> _loadChatsAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/chats.json');
  }

  Future<List<Message>> loadChats() async {
    String jsonString = await _loadChatsAsset();
    var messages = List<Message>();
    final messagesJson = json.decode(jsonString);
    for (var messageJson in messagesJson){
      messages.add(Message.fromJson(messageJson));
    }
    return messages;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadChats().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _messages.addAll(value);
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

To print something from my JSON I usually do _messages[index].sender.name or _messages[index].text etc...

The above parsing method worked without nested objects (for User only). 
With nested objects (User inside Message) I am not able to identify the source of the following error.

type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

It's happening on this line of code

> List usersList = new List.from(usersJson);

I am not sure what I am missing. Can you please assist? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be see in your json you are getting just string as a sender but when you are creating Message object then User class requires three arguments.

Means that, as a sender in json there should a user object.

```
{
   "id" : 1
    "name" : "Viren"
    "imageUrl" : 'someurl'
}
```

**Your json and your desire output is not matching.**

Moreover your following line is also wrong.

```
  sender: parseUsers(parsedJson['sender']),
```

Change to this.

```
 sender: User.fromJson(parsedJson['sender'])
```

**Update:**

Your json should be like below.

```
[
    {
        "sender": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Greg",
            "imageUrl": "assets/images/greg.jpg"
        },
        "time": "5:30 PM",
        "text": "Hey, how's it going? What did you do today?",
        "isLiked": false,
        "unread": true
    },
    {
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "James",
            "imageUrl": "assets/images/james.jpg"
        },
        "time": "4:30 PM",
        "text": "Hey, how's it going? What did you do today?",
        "isLiked": true,
        "unread": false
    }
]
```

Comment: I tried that while waiting for an answer, I got the following : _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'). Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: can you change you question with current json and what you change. did you try with changing json as i mention?

Comment: I added user json to code. It's indeed as you provided. I changed the declaration of sender to User and not List<User>. I also updated the row as you mentioned

Comment: Cool! Thank you! Appreciated!