# How to access to the API payload data structure

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API which output the following data:

```
"sun": {
        "r1": {
            "sunrise": 1698512321,
            "sunset": 1698558626
        },
        "r2": {
            "sunrise": 1698512201,
            "sunset": 1698558315
        },
        "r3": {
            "sunrise": 1698512194,
            "sunset": 1698558158
        }
  }
```

How can I access to that data on inside my flutter app?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
 final Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  for (final item in data['sun']) {

      print(item['r2']["sunrise"]); // It show me null

  }
```

I was expecting to print out `1698512201` but it show `null`

Comment: Show part of your code to obtain `response` (don't forget to hide sensitive info, if any)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `item['r2']["sunrise"]` inside your `for-in loop`.

Since your are looping through each `item` in `sun`, you can simply use

```
final Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
for (final item in data['sun']) {
  print(item['sunrise']); <-- Without ['r2']
}
```

This, will print the "sunrise" values **for each item in the sun object**.

For more example please use [these codelabs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables)

You can find more information about `for-in loop` in the [documentation](https://dart.dev/language/loops)

Comment: It show me an error `flutter: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

Comment: @mana https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459482/dart-type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-iterabledynamic does this help ?